# Python - Pandas - Apply specific function to a given Level - Multi Index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index DataFrame, and I am looking to apply some calculations only on the vector assigned to one of my levels.

Using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
ticker_date = [('US',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(3)),
('US',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(2)),
('US',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)),
('EU',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(3)),
('EU',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(2)),
('EU',datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1))]
index_df = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ticker_date)
example = pd.DataFrame([12.2,12.5,12.6,15.1,15.3,15],index_df,['value'])
```

It gives the following output:

[image]

I am looking to calculate the compounded sum of my Data, to get to this specific output. For instance, for US. 12.2, then 12.2+12.5 then 12.2+12.5+12.6

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want a `groupby` (along the 0<sup>th</sup> level) + `cumsum` -

```
df.groupby(level=0).cumsum()

               value
US 2017-12-11   12.2
   2017-12-12   24.7
   2017-12-13   37.3
EU 2017-12-11   15.1
   2017-12-12   30.4
   2017-12-13   45.4
```