# Apply custom function to multi-indexed pandas dataframe with specific groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas groupby object with 2 indices (user_id and date) and one column "operations_type" as a result of the following command:

```
grouped_count_pm = relevant.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='created_date', freq='M')], as_index=False).agg(['count'])
```

|  |  | operations_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | **count** |
| **user_id** | **date** |  |
| user_0 | 2019-04-30 | 8 |
|  | 2019-05-31 | 21 |
| user_1 | 2019-04-30 | 76 |
|  | 2019-05-31 | 35 |
| user_2 | 2019-04-30 | 6 |
|  | 2019-05-31 | 15 |

etc.

I need to calculate function trendline for each user on the basis of 2 count values and write the result into the new column, while getting rid of the additional row level for each user.
E.g, what I want to see:

| user_id | slope |
| --- | --- |
| user_0 | trendline(8, 21) |
| user_1 | trendline(76, 35) |
| user_2 | trendline(6, 15) |

So far, I've come up with this monstrosity:

```
res = {}
xs = pd.IndexSlice
users = trans_grouped_amount_pm.index.get_level_values(0)
for user_id in users:
        #  returns object with count value pair: (8,21) or (76,35) for user_id
        user_count_id = trans_grouped_count_pm.loc[xs[user_id, :], xs['operations_type', 'count']] 
        slope = trendline(np.array(user_count_id))   #  returns 1 float value for each user_id
        trans_grouped_count_pm.transform(trendline)  
        res[user_id] = slope 
res
```

The result is *technically* correct, but I'm 100% sure
a) there's more optimal way with apply() or pipe() functions,   and
b) this can be done without dict usage.

I've reviewed answers in [Applying Function to Multi Index Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901776/applying-function-to-multi-index-pandas-dataframe),[Python - Pandas - Apply specific function to a given Level - Multi Index DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814062/python-pandas-apply-specific-function-to-a-given-level-multi-index-datafra) and several others, but still it's not working.

Please, help to rewrite this into smth more reasonable.

Comment: In your code you call a `trendline` function. What is that? Also, is your desired output column `slope` of string type or something else?

Answer (score 0):

So, with the following dataframe named `df`:

```
                   count
user_0 2019-04-30      8
       2019-05-31     21
user_1 2019-04-30     76
       2019-05-31     35
user_2 2019-04-30      6
       2019-05-31     15
```

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Fake trendline function
def trendline(a, b):
    return f"trenline({a}, {b})"


# Initialize the target dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Flatten your dataframe
df = df.reset_index()

# Add users to target dataframe
new_df["user_id"] = df["level_0"].unique()

# Iterate to add values
for i in range(new_df.shape[0]):
    new_df.loc[i, "slop"] = trendline(
        df.loc[2 * i, "count"], df.loc[2 * i + 1, "count"]
    )
```

Which gets you:

```py
print(new_df)
# Outputs
  user_id              slop
0  user_0   trenline(8, 21)
1  user_1  trenline(76, 35)
2  user_2   trenline(6, 15)
```